# Convergence of product of sum, and sum of reciprocals implies equality.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

A friend claims this is true (and also claims he has a proof).

You are given the sequence $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n, \dots$ which $a_n \gt 0$ and $p_n$ is defined as:

$$ p_n = (a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n)\left(\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{a_2} + \dots + \frac{1}{a_n}\right)$$

If $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{p_n}{n^2}$$ exists (and is finite), then $a_i = a_j$ for any $i,j$.

This seems quite surprising. Is this really true?

I know we can show that the limit is $\ge 1$, by using the arithmetic and geometric mean inequality to show that $p_n \ge n^2$, but that seems to lead nowhere.

(Friend says the source is some forum he read somewhere, and does not remember).

Answer (score 5):

Suppose $a_1=2$, and $1=a_2=a_3=\cdots$.  Then $p_n=(n+1)(n-\frac 12)$, so $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{p_n}{n^2}=1$, but the desired conclusion does not hold.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $a_n \to \alpha$ for some $\alpha \neq 0$. Then we always have

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p_n}{n^2} = 1. $$

This follows from the following Abelian theorem:

> **Theorem.** If $x_n \to x$, then $\frac{1}{n}(x_1 + \cdots x_n) \to x$.

This shows that $(a_n)$ need not be eventually constant, since there are many convergent sequences which is not eventually constant.